# Adding force to a constantly moving object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

've been working on a Unity 3D game which takes place in 3D space. I can move up and down, left and right while constantly moving in the Z axis. I wanted to be able to rotate my Player gameObject with Q and E buttons to move in curves.
In regular 3D game this isnt a problem, but how do I make my Player gameObject constantly move the way its facing?

This is my current code, I can only go up,down,left,right while constantly being pushed in Z axis.

```
public float moveSpeed;
private Vector3 input;
private float maxSpeed = 10.0f;
private float bloodStream = 0.5f;
public float timer = 40.0f;



void Update () {
    if (Time.timeSinceLevelLoad >= timer)
    {
        while (bloodStream <= 0.75f)
        {
            bloodStream += Time.timeSinceLevelLoad / 10000;
        }
    }
    if (Time.timeSinceLevelLoad >= timer + 40.0f)
    {
        bloodStream = 0.5f;
    }
    input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"), bloodStream);
    if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude < maxSpeed)
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(input * moveSpeed);
    }
```

Comment: Change in constant replace value from `Force` to `Relative Force`

Comment: Sorrry I posted the wrong code previously. I tried using RelativeForce but my gameObject just felll down its movement wasnt what I wanted.

Comment: "how do I make my Player gameObject constantly move the way its facing?" It sounds like you want to use a "forward" vector from the player's local space as a force. Look at [`TransformVector`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformVector.html) or [`AddRelativeForce`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce.html) if that's true.

Comment: when using AddRelativeForce my object starts from the botton of the plane(I want it to start from a set height) and only moves if i give it an input which is not what i want.